# Textarea validation by javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, textarea

there are 2 kinds radio buttons.

If check sms button, then textarea's maxlength sets 90 bytes

If check lms button, then testarea's maxlength sets 2000 bytes

and We can check how many I put texts on the textarea at 'totalWordLimit'

but have problems

If I put many texts by copy & paste, textarea become disabled

and also when I change radio buttons, counting number doesn't initialize.

What I need to fix in this code?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var setTotalNumberOfWordCounter = "90";

function displayWordCounter(){
var getTextValue = document.smsForm.msg.value;  // Get input textarea value
var getTextLength = getTextValue.length;   // Get length of input textarea value
var one_char = "";
var rbyte = 0;
var rlen = 0;
for(var i=0; i<getTextLength; i++){
 one_char = getTextValue.charAt(i);
 if(escape(one_char).length > 4){
     rbyte += 2;                             // special language(2Bytes)
 }else{
     rbyte++;                                // 1Byte
 }

 if(rbyte <= setTotalNumberOfWordCounter){
     rlen = i+1;                             //return text count
 }
}
if(rbyte > setTotalNumberOfWordCounter){     //compare this length with total count
        getTextValue = getTextValue.substring(0,setTotalNumberOfWordCounter);
        document.smsForm.msg.value =getTextValue;
        return false;
}
 document.smsForm.totalWordLimit.value = (setTotalNumberOfWordCounter-rbyte);
 var tt = document.getElementById("Textarea");
 
 if(document.smsForm.totalWordLimit.value === "0"){   
  tt.value = tt.value.substring(0, tt.value.length-1);
 }
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide() {        
        var Textarea = document.getElementById("Textarea");         
        if(document.getElementById('sms').checked) {
         setTotalNumberOfWordCounter = "90";
        }else if(document.getElementById('lms').checked) {
      setTotalNumberOfWordCounter = "2000";
        }
         
    }    
    
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sms" id="sms" onclick="ShowHide()" value="ss" checked>SMS
<input type="radio" name="lms" id="lms" onclick="ShowHide()" value="ll"> LMS
<textarea name="msg" class="main_txt_area" id="Textarea" onkeydown="return displayWordCounter();" cols="40" rows="10" ></textarea>
         
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<div class='total_count'>total remaining Charatctor: <input type='text' class='show_count' name='totalWordLimit' size=4 readonly value="+setTotalNumberOfWordCounter+"></div>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function ShowHide() {        
    var Textarea = document.getElementById("Textarea");         
    if(document.getElementById('sms').checked) {
        Textarea.setAttribute("maxlength", "90");
    }else if(document.getElementById('lms').checked) {
        Textarea.setAttribute("maxlength", "2000");
    }

}
```

and try onpaste function in the textarea element

```
<textarea name="msg" class="main_txt_area" id="Textarea" onkeydown="return displayWordCounter();" cols="40" rows="10" onpaste="return displayWordCounter();"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!! but I can't use maxlength function, bcz I'm using other country language(1 text = 2 bytes)